# Insert array into all places in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For two arrays, say, `a = np.array([1,2,3,4])` and `b = np.array([5,6])`, is there a way, if any, to obtain a 2d array of the following form *without looping*:

```
[[5 6 1 2 3 4]
 [1 5 6 2 3 4]
 [1 2 5 6 3 4]
 [1 2 3 5 6 4]
 [1 2 3 4 5 6]]
```

i.e. to insert `b` in all possible places of `a`.

And if loops are unavoidable, how to do it the most computationally efficient way (`a` can be long, the length of `b` is irrelevant)?

Example of how it can be done using loops is trivial:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
b = np.array([5,6])
rows = len(a) + 1
cols = len(a) + len(b)
res = np.empty([rows, cols])
for i in range(rows):
    res[i, i:len(b)+i] = b
    res[i, len(b)+i:] = a[i:]
    res[i, 0:i] = a[0:i]
print(rows.astype(int))

[[5 6 1 2 3 4]
 [1 5 6 2 3 4]
 [1 2 5 6 3 4]
 [1 2 3 5 6 4]
 [1 2 3 4 5 6]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using numba acceleration. This happens to be what numba is best at. For your example, it can speed up nearly 6 times:

```
from timeit import timeit

import numpy as np
from numba import njit


a = np.arange(1, 5)
b = np.array([5, 6])


def fill(a, b):
    rows = a.size + 1
    cols = a.size + b.size
    res = np.empty((rows, cols))
    for i in range(rows):
        res[i, i:b.size + i] = b
        res[i, b.size + i:] = a[i:]
        res[i, :i] = a[:i]
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('before:', timeit(lambda: fill(a, b)))
    fill = njit(fill)
    print('after:', timeit(lambda: fill(a, b)))
```

Output:

```
before: 9.488150399993174
after: 1.6149254000047222
```

Comment: Numba is very fast. This code can be parallelized as well, which using signatures can make it more faster; Which was 3 times faster than without parallelizing on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use masking to add diagonal values `b` to the `res` array and add the rest of the cells in the array with values from `a`

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
b = np.array([5,6])

rows = len(a) + 1
cols = len(a) + len(b)
res = np.empty([rows, cols])

# Frame for masking
frame = np.arange(rows * cols).reshape(rows, cols)

diag_mask = (frame % (res.shape[1] + 1)) < (b.shape[0])
res[diag_mask] = np.tile(b, res.shape[0])
res[~diag_mask] = np.tile(a, res.shape[0])
```

Comment: I have tried to convert this code to be used by JAX library and run on GPU. The performance of this code improved multiple times using JAX on GPU on larger arrays. I added the converted code and the related benchmarks in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a zero array based on the expected shape and then fill the desired indices by the `b` values and finally fill remained zero values by tile of the `a` array with the needed shape as:

```
shape, size = a.shape[0] + 1, a.shape[0] + b.shape[0]
ind = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(np.arange(size), b.shape[0])
# [[0 1]
#  [1 2]
#  [2 3]
#  [3 4]
#  [4 5]]

zero_arr = np.zeros((shape, size), dtype=np.float64) 
zero_arr[np.arange(shape)[:, None], ind] = b
# [[5 6 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 5 6 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 5 6 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 5 6 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 5 6]]

zero_arr[zero_arr == 0] = np.tile(a, shape)
# [[5 6 1 2 3 4]
#  [1 5 6 2 3 4]
#  [1 2 5 6 3 4]
#  [1 2 3 5 6 4]
#  [1 2 3 4 5 6]]
```

### Update

**This method will beat *tax evader* method in terms of performance, on larger arrays**, if we create `zero_arr` based on any value that not contained in the `b` array. E.g. if we have `0` in `b`, so `zero_arr == 0` will misled the solution. One possible method is to use `-np.ones` with `zero_arr == -1` if `b` contains just positive values. We can create this array using `np.fill` or `np.full` if know which arbitrary value is not in that to use aforementioned indexing method; This value could be selected by using `np.arange` or `np.random` and check to find a value that is not in the `b`, too. But more comprehensive one is as below:

```
shape, size = a.shape[0] + 1, a.shape[0] + b.shape[0]
ind_0 = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(np.arange(size), b.shape[0])
ind_1 = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(np.arange(b.shape[0], size + shape - 1), a.shape[0])
ind_1 = ind_1 % size
arr = np.zeros((shape, size), dtype=np.float64)
arange_ = np.arange(shape)[:, None]
arr[arange_, ind_0] = b
arr[arange_, np.sort(ind_1)] = np.broadcast_to(a, (shape, a.shape[0]))  # or use np.tile
```

If you don't have any limitation to use other libraries (as you was agree with the numba one) and can run the code on GPU, **I believe that *JAX* library will beat numba on larger arrays.** I have converted the written codes by NumPy into JAX jitted form to see how this library can handle such matrix form problems in terms of performance. Besides the benchmarks to evaluate and compare the performances between JAX and numba on this issue, these codes have a learning aspects about how to use jax numpy where (`jnp.where`) with JAX jit decorator, where we must specify sizes **statically** in that to be workable. Another aspect was about creating [equivalent `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view` or `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` in jax jitted function by jax library](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/3171#issuecomment-1140299630). The *evader* code is converted, too, but by some changes (I think are needed for JAX usage); I don't know if I could write it in more compacted form (shorter). I think the written code can be rewritten in more optimized form which will get, even, faster codes.

```
from functools import partial
import jax
from jax.config import config
config.update("jax_enable_x64", True)
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import jit, vmap

@partial(jit, static_argnums=(1,))
def moving_window(a, size: int):
    starts = jnp.arange(len(a) - size + 1)
    return vmap(lambda start: jax.lax.dynamic_slice(a, (start,), (size,)))(starts)

@jit
def jax_initial(a, b):
    shape, size = a.shape[0] + 1, a.shape[0] + b.shape[0]
    ind = moving_window(jnp.arange(size), b.shape[0])
    arr = jnp.zeros((shape, size), dtype=jnp.float64)
    arr = arr.at[jnp.arange(shape)[:, None], ind].set(b)
    broad = jnp.ravel(jnp.broadcast_to(a, (shape, a.shape[0])))
    idx = jnp.where(arr == 0, size=broad.size) 
    return arr.at[idx].set(broad)

@jit
def jax_comp(a, b):
    shape, size = a.shape[0] + 1, a.shape[0] + b.shape[0]
    ind_0 = moving_window(jnp.arange(size), b.shape[0])
    ind_1 = moving_window(jnp.arange(b.shape[0], size + shape - 1), a.shape[0])
    ind_1 = jnp.remainder(ind_1, size)                    # ind_1 = ind_1 % size
    arr = jnp.zeros((shape, size), dtype=jnp.float64)
    arange_ = jnp.arange(shape)[:, None]
    arr = arr.at[arange_, ind_0].set(b)
    arr = arr.at[arange_, jnp.sort(ind_1)].set(jnp.broadcast_to(a, (shape, a.shape[0])))
    return arr

@jit
def jax_evader(a, b):
    shape, size = a.shape[0] + 1, a.shape[0] + b.shape[0]
    res = jnp.empty([shape, size])
    frame = jnp.reshape(jnp.arange(shape * size), (shape, size))
    diag_mask = (frame % (res.shape[1] + 1)) < (b.shape[0])
    res_0 = jnp.ravel(jnp.broadcast_to(b, (shape, b.shape[0])))  # jnp.tile(b, res.shape[0])
    res_1 = jnp.ravel(jnp.broadcast_to(a, (shape, a.shape[0])))  # jnp.tile(a, res.shape[0])
    idx = jnp.where(diag_mask, size=res_0.size)
    idx_v = jnp.where(~diag_mask, size=res_1.size)
    res = res.at[idx].set(res_0)
    return res.at[idx_v].set(res_1)
```

**some Benchmarks** [temporary link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MS_61NuT32e8AxJdZz0iIwi11emMRrM3?usp=sharing)

[image]

---

[image]

---

### **Fastest code:**

We can parallel the numba code with signatures which, on my system, ran **at least 3 times faster than the *Pig* one**:

```
a = np.random.rand(10000)
b = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], dtype=np.int64)

@nb.njit('float64[::1], int64[::1]', parallel=True)
def fill_parallel(a, b):
    rows = a.size + 1
    cols = a.size + b.size
    res = np.empty((rows, cols))
    for i in nb.prange(rows):
        res[i, i:b.size + i] = b
        res[i, b.size + i:] = a[i:]
        res[i, :i] = a[:i]
    return res
```

**numba parallelized code is the fastest code so far.**

Comment: @user7647857 , I have updated my answer and proposed the fastest form of the numba code. I have converted the proposed answers to JAX one too, which will get acceptable performances on GPU usage.